# Tag html5 <output> in IE

Tags: javascript, html

The `<output>` tag represents the result of a calculation .

Not supported in IE .

How it would be logical to use now this tag in all browser ?
All the counting will be carried out in javascript and then display in `<output>` ?

```
<form>

<input type="text" name="a" value="" onblur= "fn()">

<output name="x" for="a"></output>

</form>

<script>

function fn(){
    var num = parseInt(document.querySelector("[name='a']").value)*100;
    document.querySelector("[name='x']").value =num
}
```

Will it be semantically correct?

P.S. I use modernizr

Comment: Excluding specific styling what's the (non semantic) difference between `<output>` and `<div>`? Nothing then just make IE aware of it (sadly html5shim doesn't handle this if you use proposed snippet) and use it.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - The OPs code would not work with a div in the way that it does with a browser that fully supports `<output>` In particular, the value `num` computed in `fn()` would not become the content of the div element.

Comment: @MichaelPhelps - It is a semantically correct usage of the element. I don't understand your other questions.